# .NET async framework - is there a limitation with thread-local data

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, thread-safety, async-await

I am looking to write a Windows Service that will start various "jobs".

Each "job" will:

- be distinct in what it accomplishes
- run for the lifetime of the Service, so "long running".  Typically, a job will get 10  tasks from the database and process them, then sleep, and then repeat this cycle again and again.
- Share the same "context".  The application will be loosely coupled and call an IoC to get classes.  It will also store some data on this context too

I need each job to be able to run in parallel and effectively run as separate programs.

My first thought was to create one thread per job.  This is okay but has the drawback that a ManualResetEvent stops the thread in its tracks, and the Abort doesn't allow much chance for the Thread to exit in a graceful manner.

I then explored some of the new async framework in .NET 4.5 and boy does it seem to simplify coding.

However, whilst some of the data held on the context may be freely shared between each job, some can not: so each job requires it's own copy of certain data.

I attempted to solve this using ThreadLocal<T> properties.  However, whilst this works fine for a specific thread that I've created, this doesn't work for the async methods.  The thread that starts an async method is often not the thread that finishes the method, particularly when the method uses "await".

So, what is the preferred pattern for what I am attempting to accomplish?

FYI: [Albahari's](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) posting was a great help.

Comment: Rather than having threadlocal properties of objects shared between threads (or that are static), just *don't share objects between threads*.  Have each job create its own storage locations (i.e. object instances) in scope such that they are never accessible by the other jobs.

Comment: Agree with @Servy. You already have an IoC - why not just use that?

Comment: It isn't so much that data can't be shared (although I do go by "don't share mutable data"), I think the issue here is not supplying *all* the *relevant data* via some "aggregate [root]" that can be "re-associated" with the task. Thread locals are, as the name implies, only suitable for holding the data in a strict 1-1 thread-task correspondence ..

Comment: Passing arguments to methods is traditional way to pass arguments to methods... Why are you trying to use thread local storage? What particular problem you have regular arguments?